# java opening file doubles of ragged arrays from GUI

Tags: java

So I spent like an hour trying to figure out how to open this file from a GUI, but every time I click open file and click he file I want to open, my GUI just crashes. Here,s my code please tell me whats wrong.
This is the one given to me, so it can't be wrong.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;

public class MvGuiFx extends Application {;
    private double[][] sales;
    public static final int MAX_STORES = 6;
    public static final int MAX_ITEMS = 6;
    private NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    Button readFileBtn, exitBtn;
    GridPane dataPane;


    /**
     * Lets the user choose a file to read the sales information and displays
     * the information on the screen
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File selectedFile;

        FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
        chooser.setTitle("Choose a file to read retail items' sales information");
        if ((selectedFile = chooser.showOpenDialog(null)) != null) {
            // Read the file
            sales = TwoDimRaggedArrayUtility.readFile(selectedFile);
        }
        //display on the screen
        int row,col;
        double total;
        for(row=0;row<sales.length; row++)
            for(col=0;col<sales[row].length;col++)
                dataPane.add(new TextField(currencyFormat.format(sales[row][col])),col+1,row+1);

        //display row totals
        for(row=0;row<sales.length;row++)
        {
            total = TwoDimRaggedArrayUtility.getRowTotal(sales, row);
            dataPane.add(new TextField(currencyFormat.format(total)), 7, row+1);
        }

        //find the row with largest number of columns
        int columns = 0;
        for(row=0;row<sales.length;row++)
            if(sales[row].length > columns) columns = sales[row].length;

        //display column totals
        for(col=0;col<columns;col++)
        {
            total = TwoDimRaggedArrayUtility.getColumnTotal(sales, col);
            dataPane.add(new TextField(currencyFormat.format(total)), col+1, 7);
        }

        //find highest in each column
        for(col=0;col<columns;col++)
        {
            total = TwoDimRaggedArrayUtility.getHighestInColumn(sales, col);
            TextField temp = new TextField(currencyFormat.format(total));
            temp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: gray;");
            for(row=0;row<sales.length;row++) {
                if(col < sales[row].length){
                    if(sales[row][col]==total)
                        dataPane.add(temp, col+1, row+1);
                }
            }
        }


}

    // Handler class.
    private class ButtonEventHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            //handler for Load Sales Data
            if (e.getSource() == readFileBtn) {

                try {
                    readFile();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            //handler for Exit button
            }  else if (e.getSource() == exitBtn)

                System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Tooltip buttonToolTipArr[] = new Tooltip[5];
        buttonToolTipArr[0] = new Tooltip(
                "Load sales data from a file and Display");
        buttonToolTipArr[1] = new Tooltip("Exit Application");

        // Main Pane
        BorderPane MainPane = new BorderPane();

        // Create Title Pane, add title label and add it to the top of the Main
        // Pane
        HBox titlePanel = new HBox();
        titlePanel.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
        Label titleLbl = new Label("DisneyWorld District 5 Sales Report\n");
        titleLbl.setFont(new Font(30));
        titleLbl.setTextFill(Color.BLUE);

        titlePanel.getChildren().add(titleLbl);
        MainPane.setTop(titlePanel);

        // CenterPane
        VBox centerPane = new VBox();
        centerPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // columnHeader Pane
        HBox columnHeaderPane = new HBox(10);
        columnHeaderPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);


        int i,j;
        dataPane = new GridPane();
        dataPane.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
        dataPane.add(new Label("     "), 0, 0);
        dataPane.add(new Label("Books"), 1, 0);
        dataPane.add(new Label("Tsum Tsum"), 2, 0);
        dataPane.add(new Label("Trading Pins"), 3, 0);
        dataPane.add(new Label("Star Wars"), 4, 0);
        dataPane.add(new Label("Lego"), 5, 0);
        dataPane.add(new Label("Marvel"), 6, 0);
        dataPane.add(new Label("Total"), 7, 0);

        for(i=1;i<8;i++)
        {
            dataPane.add(new Label("     "), 0,i);
            for(j = 1; j<8;j++)
                dataPane.add(new TextField(), i,j);
        }


        dataPane.add(new Label("Emporium"), 0, 1);
        dataPane.add(new Label("World Traveler"), 0, 2);
        dataPane.add(new Label("Discovery Trading Center"), 0, 3);
        dataPane.add(new Label("Merchant of Venus"), 0, 4);
        dataPane.add(new Label("Once Upon a Toy"), 0, 5);
        dataPane.add(new Label("Tatooine Traders"), 0, 6);
        dataPane.add(new Label("Total"), 0, 7);

        // Create bottom Pane
        HBox bottomPane = new HBox(10);
        bottomPane.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);

        // Create buttons
        readFileBtn = new Button("Load Sales Data");
        readFileBtn.setTooltip(buttonToolTipArr[0]);
        exitBtn = new Button("Exit");
        exitBtn.setTooltip(buttonToolTipArr[1]);

        // add event handler to buttons
        readFileBtn.setOnAction(new ButtonEventHandler());
        exitBtn.setOnAction(new ButtonEventHandler());

        // add buttons to bottomPane
        bottomPane.getChildren().addAll(readFileBtn, exitBtn);
        MainPane.setBottom(bottomPane);

        // add panes to center pane
        centerPane.getChildren().addAll(dataPane);

        MainPane.setCenter(centerPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(MainPane, 1200, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        // Set stage title and show the stage.
        stage.setTitle("District Sales Report");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Heres what I have so far:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoDimRaggedArrayUtility {

    public TwoDimRaggedArrayUtility()
    {

    }

    public static double[][] readFile(java.io.File file) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        int row = 0;

        while(scan.hasNextLine())
        {
            row++;
        }

        double[][] array = new double[row][];

        for(int index = 0; index < array[0].length; index++)

                array[0] = new double[index];

        for(int index = 0; index < array[1].length; index++)

                array[1] = new double[index];

        for(int index = 0; index < array[2].length; index++)

                array[2] = new double[index];

        for(int index = 0; index < array[3].length; index++)

                array[3] = new double[index];

        for(int index = 0; index < array[4].length; index++)

                array[4] = new double[index];

        for(int index = 0; index < array[5].length; index++)

                array[5] = new double[index];

        for(int index = 0; index < array[6].length; index++)

                array[6] = new double[index];

        for(int index = 0; index < array[7].length; index++)

                array[7] = new double[index];

        for(int index = 0; index < array[8].length; index++)

                array[8] = new double[index];

        for(int index = 0; index < array[9].length; index++)

                array[9] = new double[index];

        for(int index = 0; index < array[10].length; index++)

                array[10] = new double[index];

        scan.close();

        return array;
    }

    public static void writeToFile(double[][] data, java.io.File outputFile)throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
    {
        PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(outputFile);
        print.print(data);
        print.close();
    }
```

And here's the ragged array .txt file:

```
1253.65 4566.50 2154.36 7532.45 3388.44 6598.23
2876.22 3576.24 1954.66
4896.23 2855.29 2386.36 5499.29
2256.76 3623.76 4286.29 5438.48 3794.43
3184.38 3654.65 3455.76 6387.23 4265.77 4592.45
2657.46 3265.34 2256.38 8935.26 5287.34
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to be honest, there's a fair bit wrong with your code.

For one thing you'd be best off avoiding the GUI altogether.  If you add the following `main` method to `TwoDimRaggedArrayUtility`, then you can run this class directly without starting up the GUI:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    double[][] sales = readFile(new java.io.File("path/to/your/file"));
    for (double[] row : sales) {
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(row));
    }
}
```

If all is well it should read in your file and print out the contents.

Firstly, your code doesn't so much crash (i.e. stop with a nasty error), it actually hangs (appears to get stuck doing nothing).

Let's start by taking a look at this loop:

```
    while(scan.hasNextLine())
    {
        row++;
    }
```

What does this do?

The answer is as follows: *while there is a next line in the scanner, add one to `row`*.

Note that at no point do you read any lines from the scanner.  So if there's any text in the scanner at all, this loop will run forever, incrementing `row` endlessly.

To read a line out of the scanner, call its `nextLine()` method.  When working with a scanner, it's common to check there's some data in there before reading that data out.  So we now have:

```
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        row++;
    }
```

If we make this change to your code, then it doesn't hang any more.  It reads all of the lines out of the file.  However, it then throws a `NullPointerException` on this line:

```
    for (int index = 0; index < array[0].length; index++)
```

To understand why, we need to take a look at the previous line:

```
    double[][] array = new double[row][];
```

What does this do?  It creates an array of 6 elements, because `row` ends up with the value `6` after finishing the `while` loop.  However, each element in the array (i.e. each 'inner' array') is `null`, because you haven't specified a size for the inner arrays.  So when you attempt to read the length of one of these arrays, you get a `NullPointerException` because there's no array to read the length of.

Putting this aside for a moment, suppose `array[0].length` returns, say, `4`.  We might then expect the following loop to run four times:

```
    for (int index = 0; index < array[0].length; index++)

        array[0] = new double[index];
```

The problem here is that the first iteration of this loop (with `index` zero) then sets `array[0]` to be an empty array.  Next time round the loop `index` is 1, but`array[0].length` is now 0, so the loop ends.

This loop isn't terribly useful, as it would only ever run once, if we were able to run it at all, and it just creates an empty array of `double`s and puts it in `array[0]`.  This loop, and the ten other loops like it, aren't worth keeping, so let's delete them all.

Let's go back to the `while` loop at the top:

```
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        row++;
    }
```

We're still not doing anything with the `line` being read in.  We want to split it up into the numbers in it and read them all in.   At the moment, we're using a scanner to split the file into lines, and we can in fact use another scanner to split the line into numbers:

```
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();

        int column = 0;
        Scanner doubleScanner = new Scanner(line);
        while (doubleScanner.hasNextDouble()) {
            double value = doubleScanner.nextDouble();
            column++;
        }

        row++;
    }
```

Note that the five lines I've inserted are similar to the `while` loop that we started with.  We check to see if there's another `double` to be read out of the doubles-scanner before we read it out, just like we did when reading lines.

This is getting us closer.  However, although we're now reading the `double` values from the line scanner, we're still not storing them anywhere.

Unfortunately, this is where things get a little fiddly here.  Java's arrays are inflexible, in that once you've created them you can't change their size.  If you want to make an array larger or smaller, you have to create a new array of the desired size and copy the values across.  For the sake of simplicity, and because this seems like a class assignment rather than actual production code, let's assume there's a maximum of 10 rows and 10 columns.  We can therefore store the values in an array by modifying our code as follows:

```
    double[][] array = new double[10][10];
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        int column = 0;
        Scanner doubleScanner = new Scanner(line);
        while (doubleScanner.hasNextDouble()) {
            array[row][column] = doubleScanner.nextDouble();
            ++column;
        }

        row++;
    }
```

I've added one line to create the array, and adjusted the line that reads `double`s out of `doubleScanner`.  Note that `new double[10][10]` is an array of 10 arrays, with each inner array having 10 elements, all initially set to zero.

At this point we should now be able to run the code and have it display some output.  However, the result isn't quite what we want, in that the rows and columns are padded with zeroes to make them up to 10-by-10.  Perhaps the simplest way to fix this is to use the [`Arrays.copyOfRange()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(double[],%20int,%20int)) methods to create a copy of only the parts of the array we're interested in, and replace the original with the copy.  We need to do this once for each row, and once for the whole array:

```
    double[][] array = new double[10][10];
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        int column = 0;
        Scanner doubleScanner = new Scanner(line);
        while (doubleScanner.hasNextDouble()) {
            array[row][column] = doubleScanner.nextDouble();
            ++column;
        }

        array[row] = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(array[row], 0, column);
        row++;
    }

    array = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, row);
```

Finally, this returns the data we wanted, without any padding zeroes.

As this is a (suspected) class assignment, please take the time to understand what this code is doing and how it works.  With software, understanding is important.  Never blindly copy code off the Internet without understanding what it does.